# Mul value in key column in mariadb

Tags: indexing, key, mariadb

I have created dept table in mariadb with dno as primary key. then I created emp table with eno as primary key and dno as foreign key as follows:

```
create table dept(dno int primary key,dname varchar(20));
create table emp(eno int primary key,ename varchar(20),dno int,foreign key(dno) references dept(dno));
```

then I describe both tables

```
DESC emp;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| eno   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| ename | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| dno   | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

desc dept;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| dno   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| dname | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

After dropping foreign key dno  from emp table it shows me the same thing in the emp table

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| eno   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| ename | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| dno   | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

how to remove mul value key column if I drop foreign key constraint

Comment: Please use proper formatting. This is unreadable

Comment: Please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.  (And it will partially answer your question.)